# Best practice for storing data from Azure Functions to Azure SQL Server via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, storing-data

Currently I have successfully implement a Azure Function (C# coding) to get the required data. Next step is to put these data on an existing Azure SQL Server.

Aside from the method that connecting manually from the Function App to the Azure SQL Server and hard coding insert data, are there others ways that I can use the result from the Function App and put in some kind of Activity in a Pipeline to store the data into a Azure SQL Server via Azure Data Factory?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Why do you need to use data factory ? Are you talking of a big amount of data ? What do you mean by hardcoding the insert ?

Comment: because this is just 1 step of a whole data collection and transformation process. By hardcoding I meant in the Azure Function, I have to connect to the Azure SQL Database, then writing Insert command within the Azure Function to insert the data I get from the Azure Function into the Azure SQL database

Comment: maybe you should have a look at logic app, it has a connector to trigger data factory pipeline.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas. Depending on what you do in your Function you might even be able to do all in the Logic App. Get the data, (transform it), store it in SQL DB.